# Entity Framework 6: Composite Key in 1:n relationship

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I have the following tables:

<kbd>Person (**string socialNumber**, string name)</kbd>

<kbd>Snapshot (**int snapshotId**, DateTime date</kbd>

<kbd>InfoOverTime (**int snapshotId, string socialNumber**, string desc, ...)</kbd>

The bold columns should be primary keys with `snapshotId` and `socialNumber` of `InfoOverTime` also being foreign keys.

I tried to create this configuration in code first like this:

```
public class Person
{
    public Person()
    {
    }

    [Key]
    public string SocialNumber { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public InfoOverTime InfoOverTime { get; set; }
}

public class Snapshot
{
    public Snapshot()
    {
    }

    public int SnapshotId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}

public class InfoOverTime
{
    public InfoOverTime()
    {
    }

    [Key, Column(Order = 0), ForeignKey("Snapshot")]
    public int SnapshotId { get; set; }
    public Snapshot Snapshot { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1), ForeignKey("Person")]
    public string PersonId { get; set; }
    public Person Person{ get; set; }

    public string Desc { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Unfortunately, I get the following error message:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.ModelValidationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
>
> InfoOverTime_Person_Source: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'InfoOverTime_Person_Source' in relationship 'InfoOverTime_Person'. Because the Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '*'.

I also tried to do it via `EntityTypeConfiguration` like this:

```
public class InfoOverTimeMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<InfoOverTime>
{
    public InfoOverTimeMap()
    {
        this.HasKey(pc => new {pc.SnapshotId, pc.PersonId});
        this.HasRequired(x => x.Snapshot).WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.SnapshotId);
        this.HasRequired(x => x.Person).WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.PersonId);
    }
}
```

But this doesn't work either :-(

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: why do you configure the keys of InfoOverTimeMap twice (via fluent api and data annotation), and the one in Snapshot not at all?

Comment: the InfoOverTimeMap-approach was just another try to do it... i deleted the annotations when trying this. the PersonId is annotated with [Key] and SnapshotId should be configured via EF itself because its called [Entity]Id or am i wrong?

Comment: sorry that was a copy paste error, its Person ofc not artist

Comment: try mapping the inverse navigation properties as well then

Answer (score 0):

you missed the following in Snapshot class:

```
public virtual InfoOverTime InfoOverTime { get; set; }
```

Comment: true :) but now i get the following error: > Additional information: An error occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key properties for their relationships. The EntityEntries property will return null because a single entity cannot be identified as the source of the exception. Handling of exceptions while saving can be made easier by exposing foreign key properties in your entity types. See the InnerException for details.

Comment: can you provide the InnerException

Comment: Also use the keyword virtual for relation entity properties: 

public virtual InfoOverTime InfoOverTime { get; set; }

Answer (score 0):

In addition to others' comment and answer, you might also have missed the "Key" attribute for Snapshot

```
[Key]
public int SnapshotId { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `public InfoOverTime InfoOverTime { get; set; }`. Besides, if you use `virtual` keyword with `Person` and `Snapshot` in `InfoOverTime`, EF can map related `Person` and `Snapshot`.

Codes should look like:

```
 public class Person
 {
    public Person()
    {
    }

    [Key]
    public string SocialNumber { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

 }

 public class Snapshot
 {
     public Snapshot()
     {
     }

    public int SnapshotId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}

 public class InfoOverTime
 {
    public InfoOverTime()
    {
    }

    [Key, Column(Order = 0), ForeignKey("Snapshot")]
    public int SnapshotId { get; set; }
    public virtual Snapshot Snapshot { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1), ForeignKey("Person")]
    public string PersonId { get; set; }
    public virtual Person Person{ get; set; }

    public string Desc { get; set; }

}
```